# ElasticSearch bucket_script aggregation result not included in results

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am running an aggregation query in ElasticSearch (version: 6). I have many documents, each having a score `some_score`, and a text array `keywords`. Now I am trying to get a list of all unique keywords, each listed along with the number of documents belonging to sectors `category1` and `category2`. The documents are divided into sectors using score ( < 50 & > 50 ). I am getting the data all right, but when I run a `bucket_script` aggregation to compute `some_metric` for each bucket ( or keyword ), the `bucket_script` result is not included in the results. No error is shown as well.

Query:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/my_index/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "keywords_by_sector": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "keywords.keyword",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sectors": {
          "filters": {
            "filters": {
              "category1": {
                "range": {
                  "some_score": {
                    "from": 0,
                    "to": 50
                  }
                }
              },
              "category2": {
                "range": {
                  "some_score": {
                    "from": 51,
                    "to": 100
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "some_metric": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "varr": "sectors['category1']>_count"
            },
            "script": "params.varr*10"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Results:

```
{
  "took" : 12,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 6,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "keywords_by_sector" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "keyword1",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "sectors" : {
            "buckets" : {
              "category1" : {
                "doc_count" : 0
              },
              "category2" : {
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            }
          },
          /* I expect some_metric to be included here */
        },
        ...
        ...
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What am I getting wrong, and why is the field not included in the results, without any error?

Comment: Hi Dane! Have you had any luck in fixing this? I am stuck with the same problem!

Comment: Also my problem that is not solved yet!